# VBNET Confuse Using Checkbox and Select Case

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am trying to do some case with choosing more then one checkbox.

so i would like to choose 2 checkbox (checkbox1 and 2) and make linklabel1.text = Banana
then 3 checkbox (checkbox1, 2, and 3) and make linklabel2.text = Apple, in conclusion if I choose checkbox1, 2 and 3, linklabel1 and 2 will show changes (Banana and Apple shown)

this is my snapshot [image: form snapshot]

and this is what I try, but nothing happen

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim fruit() As String = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"}
    Select Case fruit.ToString
        Case CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked 
            LinkLabel1.Text = fruit(0)
        Case CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked
            LinkLabel2.Text = fruit(1)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not using `Select Case` correctly. This would be better suited for `If/Else`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Select Case fruit.ToString` is incorrect. You want to check the Checkboxes not the fruit string.

And you should use an IF statement:

```
Dim fruit() As String = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"}

If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
    LinkLabel1.Text = fruit(0)
End If
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked Then
    LinkLabel2.Text = fruit(1)
End If
```

This will work too:

```
Dim fruit() As String = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"}

If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
    LinkLabel1.Text = fruit(0)

    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        LinkLabel2.Text = fruit(1)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` tests are comparing the values of `CheckBox1` with the array `fruit`. Which in basic terms, have nothing to do with each others. When you specify a variable in `SELECT`, you must check for values that can occur to that variable in the following `CASE`s.

In simple words, here is how `SELECT/CASE` works

```
Select Case drink
  Case "water"
      MsgBox("the variable [drink] has the value [water]")
  Case "cola"
      MsgBox("the variable [drink] has the value [cola]")

End Select
```

In your case, you did something like

```
Select Case drink
    Case weather.IsHot
          'no logic in comparing [drink] with [weather.IsHot] because 
          'this is equivellent CASE TRUE/FALSE
    Case car.IsRed
          'same as above
    Case food.IsSalty And phone.IsRinging
          'same as above
End Select
```

So here is what you need to modify to get your code to work:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
            LinkLabel1.Text = fruit(0)
ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked And CheckBox3.Checked Then
            LinkLabel2.Text = fruit(1)
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how LinkLabel4 fits into the picture...

...but based on your explanation, I would do it this way:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim fruit() As String = {"Banana", "Apple", "Orange"}
    Dim LLs() As LinkLabel = {LinkLabel1, LinkLabel2, LinkLabel3}
    Dim CBs() As CheckBox = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}

    For Each LL As LinkLabel In LLs
        LL.Text = ""
    Next
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To CBs.Length - 1
            If CBs(i).Checked Then
                LLs(i - 1).Text = fruit(i - 1)
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```